# how to store value of multiselect listbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, listbox

I have one multiselect listbox in my HTMl.
I want to get values of selected items of listbox in javascript

My html code:

```
<select id="schools" size="5" multiple="multiple">
<option value="352">Byskovskolen</option>
<option value="355">Heldagsskolen Specialtilbud</option>
<option value="372">Plejecenter Solbakken</option>
</select>
```

My Javascript code:

```
function getData()
{
var allSchools = [];
 var s = document.getElementById("schools");
            alert("schools lenght  " + s.options.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < s.options.length; i++) {
                if (s.options[i].selected == true) {
                    var schoolid = s.options[i].value;
                    alert(s.options[i].value);
                        allSchools.push(schoolid);
                }
            }
}
```

Values can be seen alerted with alert box but not getting stored in variable.

How can I store it in variable.

Comment: You have commented out the main line bro ;)

Comment: That was by mistake done while copying code to this question. It shows undefined when I show schoolid in alertbox.

Comment: :I have replicated same on Jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/AHA4a/. just ignore that i have used Jquery there for click event initiation,but your code is intact, i havent done any changes to it.

Comment: I cant see anything working there.

Comment: Cant You see that the alert is actually printing the value of "schoolid" variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine if you comment/uncomment the right lines. Try this:

```
function getData() {
    var allSchools = [];
    var s = document.getElementById("schools");
    for (var i = 0; i < s.options.length; i++) {
        if (s.options[i].selected == true) {
            var schoolid = s.options[i].value;
            allSchools.push(schoolid);
        }
    }
    console.log(allSchools);
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/4qYht/1/

Answer (score 0):

Uncommented one line (var schoolid) and added a print out for the allSchools variable.

```
function getData()
{
var allSchools = [];
var s = document.getElementById("schools");
        alert("schools lenght  " + s.options.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < s.options.length; i++) {
            if (s.options[i].selected == true) {
                var schoolid = s.options[i].value;
                allSchools.push(schoolid);
            }
        }
console.log(allSchools);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

uncomment the schoolid assignment line

```
var schoolid = s.options[i].value;
allSchools.push(schoolid);
```

or

use `allSchools.push(s.options[i].value);` instead of `allSchools.push(schoolid);`

Answer (score 0):

You have commented out the main line ,which would store the value in a variable.

`//  var schoolid = s.options[i].value;`

apart from that rest of your code is perfect.

**here is the corrected code :**

```
function getData()
 {
    var allSchools = [];
    var s = document.getElementById("schools");
    alert("schools lenght  " + s.options.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < s.options.length; i++) {
         if (s.options[i].selected == true) {
          //  var schoolid = s.options[i].value;
           alert(s.options[i].value);
           allSchools.push(schoolid);
         }
    }
  }
```

Happy coding:)